# In the Saving Private Ryan movie what did corporal Upman say to his German prisoners of war?

Tags: meaning, question

In the closing scenes of Saving Private Ryan corporal Upham has taken some German soldiers at gun point. Suddenly, he shoots one without provacation. Then, instead of shooting the others he says "Verschwindet!" and the prisoners scatter. I wasnt sure what that word meant so I looked it up in a German-English dictionary and it means "Disappear". I don't know how to translate that because why would Upham tell the soldiers to "disappear"? It doesn't make sense. I have studied german in college about 32 years ago and my german is rusty but I can still read enough german that I read Luther's German "modern" translation. I just don't know how to translate Upham's exclamation. It makes no sense in context.

Comment: Why doesn't it make sense in the context? He says "disappear" and they run away. Is that not disappearing?

Comment: Any dictionary providing only a single translation should be considered with suspicion, a decent one answers the question, see e.g. [pons](https://de.pons.com/%C3%BCbersetzung/deutsch-englisch/verschwinden).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In that context "Verschwindet!" means "Go away!", "Get lost!".

Upham could stop himself from killing those soldiers and tells them to get lost before he would change his mind (again) and shoot them like the first one.

Comment: So, it could be translated as "scram!"

Comment: @SaberTruthTiger yes, indeed